# Creating a new cell in Jupyter notebook using javascript API from a imported module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a new cell programmatically using the `IPython.display.Javascript` API.
The following code  is able to create a new cell when executed from a cell.

```
import IPython
opts = ["ls", "-l"]
IPython.display.Javascript("""
        var cell = Jupyter.notebook.insert_cell_below('code')
        cell.set_text("%time {}")
        cell.execute()""".format(' '.join(opts))
    )
```

However when I put it inside a function (say create_cell) in a module (say cell_test.py) call it from the notebook as follows, it doesn't not do anything at all.

```
import cell_test
cell_test.create_cell()
```

The content of the module is:

```
# module call_test
def create_cell():
    import IPython
    opts = ["ls", "-l"]
    IPython.display.Javascript("""
        var cell = Jupyter.notebook.insert_cell_below('code')
        cell.set_text("%time {}")
        cell.execute()""".format(' '.join(opts))
    )
```

What is going on here? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add "return", i.e.,

```
# module call_test
def create_cell():
    import IPython
    opts = ["ls", "-l"]
    return IPython.display.Javascript("""
        var cell = Jupyter.notebook.insert_cell_below('code')
        cell.set_text("%time {}")
        cell.execute()""".format(' '.join(opts))
    )
```